# Вопрос по работе с рекурсивными функциями ( задача: числа Капрекара)

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, рекурсия

Спасибо, что помогаете разбираться и изучать python. Работа с функциями сейчас больше всего вызывает вопросов. Например сейчас не понимаю, почему мы не можем получить L из def numerics(n), ведь мы возвращаем return(L) и передать в kaprekar_step(L) и так по цепочке передавать выход с одной ф-и на вход последующей? В kaprekar_loop(n) пытался организовать рекурсию выход из которой по достижению условия if, но не доходит до этого шага, выкидывая ошибку.

По отдельности функции работают, но как передать параметры и осуществить рекурсивный вызов(если он вообще тут необходим)- не понимаю.

Буду признателен за любую помощь с функциями, будь то идеи по решению или простые задачки на тренировку работы с функциями.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jailed_code", line 35, in <module>
    kaprekar_loop(n)
  File "jailed_code", line 29, in kaprekar_loop
    kaprekar_step(L)
NameError: name 'L' is not defined
```

[image: алгоритм поиска числа Капрекара]

```
def numerics(n):
    L = []
    n = str(n)
    for i in range(4):
        L.append(n[i])

    for j in range(4):
        L[j] = int(L[j])

    kaprekar_step(L)

def kaprekar_step(L):
    max = sorted(L)
    min = sorted(L, reverse=True)

    maxS = str(max[0])+str(max[1])+str(max[2])+str(max[3])
    minI=int(maxS)
    #print(maxS)
    minS = str(min[0])+str(min[1])+str(min[2])+str(min[3])
    maxI=int(minS)
    #print(minS)
    n = maxI - minI

    kaprekar_loop(n)

def kaprekar_loop(n):
    while True:
        print (n)
        #return(n)
        if n==6174:
            break
        else:
            numerics(n)

n = 8654
numerics(n)
```

Comment: Мало вернуть значение из самой функции, надо его куда-то сохранить там, где функция вызывается. А этого в коде как раз нет. Куда сохраняются результаты numerics(n) и kaprekar_step(L)? Никуда.

Comment: И вообще, если выкидывает ошибку, то а) полезно ее читать, б) текст ошибки нужно копировать в вопрос.

Comment: я думал они будут сохраняться в переменную возвращаемую return ом.

Comment: Нет, не будут. Эта переменная за пределами функции вообще не существует.

Comment: Т.е нужно переменные, возвращаемые return, сделать глобальными?

Comment: Нет. Нужно результат функции присвоить переменной.  a = numerics(n). Перечитайте главу про использование функций.

Comment: я почитал и посмотрел на форумах и здесь https://stepik.org/lesson/24460/step/7?unit=6766 , но в основном расказывется как перадать аргументы в ф-ю, а получить результат можно только return или через global, nonlocal. Возможно я что то пропустил. Немного изменил код, что бы одна ф-я вызывала другую в своем теле, тогда переменную не придется выводить из локальной области видимости. Но возникла проблема. Я где то создал бесконечный цикл и вызовы не прекращаются, хотя условие выхода n==6174 уже исполнилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При работе с рекурсивными функциями чаще всего вы возвращаете вызов этой же функции с измененным аргументом. Рекурсия заканчивается при выполнении определенного условия (в вашем случае когда аргумент функции будет равен `6174`) и при выполнении данного условия мы возвращаем уже не вызов той же функции а что-то более материальное - число, переменную или что-то подобное.

Пример с функцией Капрекара:

```
def kaprekar(n, verbose=0):
    if n == 6174:
        return n   # здесь стек начнёт вычитываться и опустошаться, начиная с последнего
    nums = str(n)
    a = int(''.join(sorted(nums, reverse=True)))
    b = int(''.join(sorted(nums)))
    x = a - b
    if verbose > 0:
        print(f'{a} - {b} = {x}')
    return kaprekar(x, verbose=verbose)  # эти вызовы попадают в стек
```

Результат:

```
In [9]: kaprekar(7339, verbose=1)
9733 - 3379 = 6354
6543 - 3456 = 3087
8730 - 378 = 8352
8532 - 2358 = 6174
Out[9]: 6174
```

Comment: спасибо, красивое решение. Но остается не понятным зачем необходима verbose=0? И можно ли решить задачу без рекурсии? Т.к я решаю задачи на сайте, там грейдер проверки требует наличие ф-й numerics(n), kaprekar_step(L),kaprekar_loop(n).

Comment: Не понимаю, почему у меня в цикле while  не происходит прерывание цикла и  завершение фунции, при наступлении n==6174.

Comment: @AlexSapsay, параметр `verbose` отвечает за отладочную информацию, при `verbose=0` отладочная информация не печатается.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за идеи и советы по работе с рекурсивными функциями, это помогло найти решение и грейдер поругался предупреждениями но принял решение! Организовал выход из функции через sys.exit()

```
import sys

def numerics(n):
    L = []
    n = str(n)
    for i in range(4):
        L.append(n[i])

    for j in range(4):
        L[j] = int(L[j])

    kaprekar_step(L)

def kaprekar_step(L):
    max = sorted(L)
    min = sorted(L, reverse=True)

    maxS = str(max[0])+str(max[1])+str(max[2])+str(max[3])
    minI=int(maxS)
    #print(maxS)
    minS = str(min[0])+str(min[1])+str(min[2])+str(min[3])
    maxI=int(minS)
    #print(minS)
    n = maxI - minI

    kaprekar_loop(n)

def kaprekar_loop(n):
    while True:
        print (n)
        #return(n)
        if n==6174:
            #return n
            sys.exit()
        else:
            numerics(n)
```

Comment: лучше приучиться писать функции так чтобы они возвращали значения и пользоваться возвращенными значениями. Тогда не пришлось бы пользоваться `sys.exit()`. Ни одна из трех ваших функций ничего не возвращает. Если бы вы немного подробнее описали что ожидает "autograder" от каждой из этих функций, то можно было бы дать более конкретный ответ

Comment: @MaxU, да я понимаю, что мой код сейчас спагетти. Я не совсем понял, как можно сохранить значение переданное функцией через  return, чтобы использовать это значение в качестве аргумента для следующей ф-и. Не понимаю как достать значение из return х. Если мы присвоим х= res в теле ф-и, то он останется локальным и будет недоступен.

Comment: Можете ли посоветовать сайты с самыми простыми задачками на функции? Чтобы отработать эту тему.

Comment: `res = func(...)` - в итоге в переменной `res` значение которое вернула функция `func(...)`

Comment: я такими сайтами сам не пользовался пожтому не посоветую... Давайте вместе усовершенствуем данный ответ? Поэтому я и спросил что ожидает грейдер от каждой из этих функций...

Answer (score 0):

Как посоветовали MaxU и Эникейщик - разобраться с функциями, то не буду откладывать сложную задачку в долгий ящик ( хоть и слабо понимаю как ее решить ) и пробую собрать все функции и организовать передачу параметров между ними.
Пока не разобрался еще как тут на StackOverflow идет комментирование и правки, обсуждения, поэтому может быть не оптимально написано.

**План:**

1. Организуем проверку на число Капрекара.
2. Если число прошло проверку- то преобразуем в мин макс и находим разность.
3. добавить проверку числа по его нахождению в списке и выход из ф-и.

[image: алгоритм поиска числа Капрекара в ф-и]

[image: Задание. Поиск чисел Капрекара]

```
    import sys

buffL_for_print=[]

# запуск функции проверки на число Капрекара(через рекурсию?)
# дополнительная проверка в множестве для 6-ти значных чисел
def kaprekar_check(n):
    nn = str(n)
    num_str=[]

    for i in range(len(nn)):
        num_str.append(int(nn[i]))

    my_set = set(num_str)

    if (len(nn) != 3 and len(nn) != 4 and len(nn) != 6) or (n == 100 or n == 1000 or n == 100000 or len(my_set) == 1):
        print("Ошибка! На вход подано число " +str(n)+", не удовлетворяющее условиям процесса Капрекара")
        sys.exit()    
    else:
        return (n)


#  Напишите функцию numerics(n), принимающую на вход 1 натуральное число, 
#  а возвращающую список цифр из которых состоит число
def numerics(n):
    L=[]
    nums = str(n)
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        L.append(int(nums[i]))
    return L


#  Функция должна сформировать внутри 2 числа:
def kaprekar_step(L):    
    nums = L
    # проверка нахождения ответа списке, выход при нахождении элемента в списке
    if str(L) not in buffL_for_print: # формируем список всех пробегающих чисел
        buffL_for_print.append(str(L))# формируем множество уникальных чисел
    else:
        for i in range(len(buffL_for_print)):# вывод уникальных чисел из множества и завершение п-мы

            buff_num = buffL_for_print[i]
            buff_num = buff_num[1:-1]
            buff_num = buff_num.replace(",","")
            buff_num = buff_num.replace(" ","")
            print(int(buff_num))
            buff_num = int(buff_num)

            L_for_print = int(''.join([str(i) for i in nums]))

            if (buff_num == 495 or buff_num == 6174 or buff_num == 549945 or buff_num == 631764):
                sys.exit()

        print("Следующее число - "+str(L_for_print)+", кажется процесс зациклился...")
        sys.exit()



    a = int(''.join([str(i) for i in (sorted(nums, reverse=True))]))
    b = int("".join([str(i) for i in (sorted(nums))]))
    x = a - b
    return x

# конечная функция
def kaprekar_loop(n):
    n = kaprekar_check(n) # зачем возвращать True or False, если я их не буду использовать?
    L = numerics(n)# принимает число n, возвращает список цифр n
    x = kaprekar_step(L) # принимает L- список чисел, возвращает разницу между макс и мин
    kaprekar_loop(x)

n = 103303
kaprekar_loop(n)
```